# Should I create for each view (block) a different controller?

Tags: angularjs, controller

If I have an page like this below:

```
<body>
   <div id="headerBlock"></div>
   <div id="mainBlock"></div>
   <div id="footerBlock"></div>
</body>
```

say for example that all of those views/blocks have some logic, should them have a their own controller?

Comment: your reusing the elements anywhere in the page , its better to write a reusable directive,with isolate scope which acts as a web components. Its better to reuse and keep your application DRY (dont repeat yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to reuse it in different pages, they should be implemented with directives, then you could give a controller to each directive.

They can have their own controller, unless you need the footer to interact with the header, but that is not the common case. And like that you can use your header or your footer independently on your application.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to share ui code then a good way is to use directives

Check this sample

http://gon.to/2013/03/23/the-right-way-of-coding-angularjs-how-to-organize-a-regular-webapp/

Comment: My question is "should them have their own controller? or a main one for all of these three views?"
Because I can share "headerBlock" and "footerBlock" with other pages.